# UPDATE each row of MySQL with different value in Python

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop

To sum it up. I have data in a row of a db (MySQL). This data are used in the script to calculate a value. A for loop is used to calculate this value for each row in the table.
The Problem: The results stored in the variable meant have to be updated in a different column of the same row.

I tried to include the update command in the for loop but I get an error (see below). If I do not include the update-command in the for loop I just get the result of the last row but for all rows!

The script:

```
for row in rows:
     for col in row:
           x = map(str.strip,col.lower().split())
           st = map(lambda wo: abo.get(wo, 0), x)
           meant = numpy.meant(st)
           cur.execute("""UPDATE table_x SET result = %s Where text = %s""",(meant, rows))
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
Programming Error: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual...
```

How can I update the column with each calculated value (meant) of that row?

Comment: DO NOT strip the error message. Please show the entire error message

Comment: I'm pretty new to python myself, but: I think using triple-quotes on your query there actually comments it out, so effectively you are using `cur.execute(,(meant, rows))` as your query command

Comment: @khaverim No, triple quotes don't mean comment.

Comment: @hjpotter92 They certainly do in Python. I've used them a lot...but what I gather from that is that within a method like `.execute()` the triple-quote doesn't comment things out. Thanks

Comment: The description and code are a little confusing. Could you provide a simple example of the original says and how that data should be updated after the calculation?

Comment: @khaverim no they do not. They absolutely, definitely do not. They just mark whatever is in them as a string. If you have that string on a line by itself then it does nothing, which is the same effect as a comment, but it's still defining a string.

Comment: ummm both? https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2004-February/028432.html `""" this is a multiline comment
  which spawns many lines
"""` -multiline comments are also used to embed what are called doc strings in a function

Comment: This is what I did prior the loop to get the data from the db    fromdb = cur.execute("SELECT region FROM table_x WHERE searchterm = 'italy'")
rows = cur.fetchall()

Comment: Error Message
  File "C:\Users\Claudio\Documents\SeAB.py", line 43, in <module>
    cur.execute("""UPDATE table_x SET result = %s Where text = %s""",(meant, row))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")

Answer (score 0):

As I see `rows` is a list ( or an iterable )

and in your query, you are binding the placeholder with `rows` ( instead of `row`? )

`cur.execute("""UPDATE table_x SET result = %s Where text = %s""",(meant, rows)`

That would most probably create a syntax error.

Comment: I think row is iterable as well

Comment: Thanks very much for help. I changed it to row but without success... Error message: ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")                                                                I used rows because I declared rows = cur.fetchall() before the for loops